# How do I create a new button (button to calculate a financial input by user) depending on which option they choose from a dropdown menu in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to code a GUI with three tabs - the first being used to calculate financial ratios based on what option the user picks from the dropdown menu. How do I code something for entry boxes, labels and "calculate" buttons to be shown on the window. For example, if the user picks "gross margin" on the menu, I would like a label, entry and calculate button to show with two entry boxes for a gross profit and a sales value to be entered by the user which the program should compute and output.

I have tried to create a function to complete this but have not had any luck. How can I code something to the above specifications?

The code is below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
tabControl.add(tab3, text='Tab 3')
tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

OPTIONS = ["Gross Margin", "Operating Margin", "Net Profit Margin"]
variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set("Pick a calculation")
w = tk.OptionMenu(tab1, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.grid(column=0, row=1)

ttk.Label(tab1,
          text="Profitability Ratios").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)
ttk.Label(tab2,
          text="Lets dive into the world of computers").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)
ttk.Label(tab3,
          text="My third tab for my coursework").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)

def gross_margin():
    if tk.OptionMenu == OPTIONS[0]:
        gp = Label(root, tab1, text="Enter Gross Profit Value:", command=gross_margin()).pack()
        gpe = Entry(root, tab1, textvariable=grossprofit, command=gross_margin()).pack()
        salesentry = Label(root, tab1, text="Enter Sales Value:", command=gross_margin()).pack()
        salese = Entry(root, tab1, textvariable=sales, command=gross_margin()).pack()
        x = gpe / salese
        Label(root, tab1, text=x, command=gross_margin()).pack()
```

I'd appreciate any guidance as I'm new to Tkinter!
Thanks in advance

Comment: With the code you have already got, what error are you facing? A traceback of the same might also be helpful, perhaps to find the possible correction in your own code perhaps a minute detail you missed.

Comment: @typedecker I want an entry box and label to appear when I click gross margin from the dropdown menu and for it to compute the calculation. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I meant to ask for any error you might have encountered running the current code? does that not generate the desired result?

Comment: @typedecker ahhh my bad, I have not received any errors with the code and there seems to be no change when I do click the gross margin option from the menu